# how <c-r>= works in vim

Tags: vim

Adding the code in vimrc causing

```
"E488: Trailing characters: <c-r>=12+34<cr>"
```

always shows up

```
<c-r>=12+34<cr>
```

what's going on there?

my original code:

```
function! CleverTab()
    if strpart( getline('.'), 0, col('.')-1 ) =~ '^\s*$'
        return "\<Tab>"
    endif
    if pumvisible()
        return "\<C-N>"
    endif
    let s:codecompl = CodeComplete()
    "<c-r>=s:codecompl<cr>
    <c-r>=12+34<cr>
    "exec " " .s:codecompl. "\<enter>"."."
    "if g:swith_region_flag == 1
    "    return SwitchRegion()
    "else return s:codecompl
    return ''
endfunction
```

Comment: what code are you adding to vimrc add what are you trying ta achieve?

Comment: thanks for you reply. Actually, i just wanna understand how it works. for instance, if "something ture" do the command above, else do nothing. However, that error E448 pops up all the time. it is quite annoy!!!

Comment: What did you want `<c-r>=12+34<cr>` in your .vimrc to do? it seems to not make any sense.

Comment: it seems like "<c-r>=" always work together with mapping, so how it work without mapping?

Comment: actually, what i wanna do is if something ture, run <c-r>=CodeComplete(), else do other things. really hope any tips.

Comment: How are you using this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<C-R>` is an insert-mode command, you cannot simply put it in a Vimscript function, which executes Ex commands. Instead you'd have to use `:normal! i` to issue the normal mode command `i` to re-enter insert mode. Use `:execute` to be able to use the `<...>` key notation, and you get:

```
:execute "normal! i\<c-r>=12+34\<cr>"
```

That said, when you're in a map-expression that returns keys (as you appear to be here), you can't use `:normal` (the text is locked), and you should just `:return` the keys:

```
:return "\<c-r>=12+34\<cr>"
```